# Modifying default workbench view filter via code

Tags: views, 8

Workbench ships the 'My Content' view default in code. I want it to actually show "my content" by adding a contextual filter with the author by field = current user.

I've looked into http://blog.arvixe.com/altering-default-views-in-code/, but it is a drupal 7 implementation and doesn't touch on the filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred approach to do those things in Drupal 7 is to:

1. Clone "My content" view to "My content clone view".
2. Make modifications to "My content clone view"
3. Disable "My content" (the original view).

I still haven't tried this in Drupal 8, but I think the principle should be the same.

Regards,
Oleg

Comment: After looking at it for awhile, I tend to agree. Especially since the original "My content" page that comes with Workbench has a view embedded in another view that I don't think we want.

Comment: It makes the things way more cleaner and elegant, if you ask me.
If that answers your question would you mind checking the answer as accepted ? Best regards, Oleg